# I need help with this simple problem in little-o notation

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, functions, notation

$\left(x-\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{6}+\displaystyle\frac{x^5}{120} +o(x^5)\right)\left(1+\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{2}-\displaystyle\frac{x^4}{24}+ \displaystyle\frac{x^4}{8}+o(x^4)\right) = x+\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{3}+\displaystyle\frac{2x^5}{15}+o(x^5)$

I got $\ x+ \displaystyle\frac{x^3}{3}+\displaystyle\frac{x^5}{120}-\displaystyle\frac{7x^7}{720}+\displaystyle\frac{x^9}{1440} $

How am I going to get $\displaystyle\frac{2}{15}x^5$? I know that $x^7=o(x^5),x^9=o(x^5)$, but how do coefficients behave?

Comment: Please don't post  the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606357/could-anyone-explain-to-me-how-did-we-get-this-result-this-is-simple-example-bu) twice.

Comment: If the 2nd factor is in $o(x^4)$, the product will also be in $o(x^4)$. Please check your 2nd factor.

Answer (score 0):

Coefficients behave as normal (up to and including $x^5$ - the $o(x^5)$ term can conceal any amount of higher-order terms), so either the question is incorrect or you copied down the question wrong. In particular you have two consecutive terms with $x^4$ in the second part - are you sure those are both correct?

Comment: I copied it right i would post a picture, but I am new to this site and I don't know how. I got this problem from workbook of previous colloquiums and finals at my college so I assume the answer is right.. There was no errors in previous problems

Comment: Those are 2 last steps of the problem. Two x^4 terms are here to indicate what ahd happened after previous step.